# Insert value through procedure in a table by mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements, phpmyadmin, insert

I want to insert values into a table by using a procedure. I have 2 tables `sales` and `products`; in the `product` table I have columns `id, product_name,product_price, product_quantity` and in `sales` table I have `p_id` and `p_qty`.

I want to use a procedure when a user add values in a `sales` table; this procedure should take 2 arguments for `p_id` and `p_qty`.

If `p_qty` is less than 0 or greater than `product_quantity`, then showstock is not available

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tkZe.png)

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You can't use `products.product_quantity` outside of a query of the table. What is `product_qty_proc > products.product_quantity` supposed to mean? The `products` table has many rows, which quantity do you want to compare with?

Comment: product quantity from products table like 20, 30 ... while in a sales table user could not be able to add value if user add quantity above the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my query

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE find_qty_(
    product_id_proc INT,
    product_qty_proc INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        remaining_stock INT; 
        SELECT product_quantity INTO remaining_stock FROM products
        WHERE id = product_id_proc; 
        IF product_qty_proc>=0 OR product_qty_proc>remaining_stock THEN 
            BEGIN SELECT "stock not available";
            END;
        ELSE 
            INSERT into sales(p_id,p_qty)VALUES(product_id_proc,product_qty_proc);
        END IF; 
    END;;
```

Comment: The question says "less than 0", why is your condition `>=0`?

Comment: Both conditions are true. 0 or less than zero stock is not available in both conditions

Comment: Oh, now I see you have the `INSERT` in `ELSE` rather than `IF`, so the condition is opposite.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: my query was , i want to insert values in a sales table with two parameters first one is product_id_proc 
     and the other one is product_qty_proc if user add product quantity more than the value which was in product table quantity it should be an error  display  which shows stock not available or incase user quantity is less than or equal to product table quntity than value should be insert in sales table note initially sales table is blank, my error was occure in conditional statement therefore all the data was insert in the sales table while  product quantity is greater than the stock,

Comment: i have resolve my query first i store  product table's quantity in a varible after that i used this varibale for comparison

Comment: i hope it will be clear...

Answer (score 0):

`product_qty_proc > products.product_quantity` needs to refer to a specific row in the `products` table in a query. You can use a subquery to select the quantity for `product_id_proc`. Replace that condition with:

```
product_qty_proc > (
    SELECT product_quantity 
    FROM products 
    WHERE product_id = product_id_proc
)
```

Also, `product_qty_proc>0` should be `product_qty_proc<0`.